# Как выделать буквы?

Tags: орфография

Как лучше?

> Если есть слово с буквой Е, то пишется не О, а Ё, напр.: *дешевый — дешёвка*. Обратите внимание, что слово *жопяной*, образованное от *жопа*, пишется с О!

> Если есть слово с буквой *е*, то пишется не *о*, а *ё*, напр.: *дешевый — дешёвка*. Обратите внимание, что слово *жопяной*, образованное от *жопа*, пишется с *о*!

> Если есть слово с буквой **е**, то пишется не **о**, а **ё**, напр.: *дешевый — дешёвка*. Обратите внимание, что слово *жопяной*, образованное от *жопа*, пишется с **о**!

> Если есть слово с буквой ***е***, то пишется не ***о***, а ***ё***, напр.: *дешевый — дешёвка*. Обратите внимание, что слово *жопяной*, образованное от *жопа*, пишется с ***о***!

Comment: Минус плюс побьет!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все варианты верны. А также можно использовать кавычки. [«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=253755):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]